# Is there a code for JavaScript to automatically click Next

Tags: javascript, html

I’m currently working on writing a code in the Console tool on Chrome that selects a certain value and clicks the Next button to move onto the next page.

```
<input type="Submit" value=" Next >>" onclick="return fnValidate(form);"> == $0
```

Comment: '''<input type="Submit" value=" Next >>" onclick="return fnValidate(form);". == $0'''

Comment: Yes you can tell Javascript to automatically click a button. You can google how to do that quite easily. But this button has no ID or class attributes, so locating it in the DOM might be tricky, unless you can find it reliably in relation to other elements nearby.

Comment: Right that’s a trouble I was running into the fact that there is no ID.

Comment: ok well it might have been better to make that clear in the original question. (You can edit your question btw, there is an "edit" button just below it). Anyway basically you can try using attribute selectors to find it, or try finding it by its location as I described above. Both of these techniques should be google-able.